# How can I use a non-SolidColor brush for WinRT xaml TextBox foreground color?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to style a TextBox such that the text is rendered with an Image brush, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Given, the following snippet, I am able to set the text to render with a solid color brush. However, if I instead try to use either of the commented out brushes (LinearGrad or ImageBrush), it just renders as solid black text.

```
        <TextBox Text="test" Background="{x:Null}" FontSize="64">
            <TextBox.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Plum"/>

                <!--<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>-->
                <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:/Assets/Texture.png"/>-->
            </TextBox.Foreground>

        </TextBox>
```

I can do the same thing to style a TextBlock, but it doesn't seem to work on a TextBox. Is there something I'm missing? The documentation makes no mention about any limitations or exceptions: [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.foreground%28v=vs.10%29.aspx)

To be clear, this is NOT a WPF question. I know this works in WPF, this is a Windows 8 App (WinRT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it might be an undocumented unsupported scenario based on my testing. If you really need to do it though - you could create a custom template of the `TextBox` that displays a `TextBlock` when the control is not in use and template-bind the `TextBlock.Foreground` and other properties to the respective `TextBox` properties.